# Object-based Radix Sort via an Iteratee

Tags: algorithm, typescript

I recently finished implementing a radix sort for objects where either one of the keys is numeric, or can be expressed numerically via an iteratee.

```
type KeysCorrespondingToValueType<T, V> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

type Iteratee<T, V> = KeysCorrespondingToValueType<T, V> | ((item: T) => V);

function getValueFromIteratee<T, V>(
  item: T,
  iteratee: Iteratee<T, V>
) {
  return typeof iteratee === 'function' ? iteratee(item) : item[iteratee];
}

function radixSortBy<
  T extends Record<KeysCorrespondingToValueType<T, number>, number>
>(items: T[], iteratee: Iteratee<T, number>) {
  function partialGetValueFromIteratee(item: T) {
    return getValueFromIteratee(item, iteratee);
  }

  const maxDigits = items.reduce(
    (previousValue, currentValue) =>
      Math.max(
        previousValue,
        getNumDigits(partialGetValueFromIteratee(currentValue))
      ),
    -Infinity
  );

  let negativeWhenTransformedItems: T[] = [];
  let positiveWhenTransformedItems: T[] = [];

  items.forEach((item) => {
    if (partialGetValueFromIteratee(item) < 0) {
      negativeWhenTransformedItems.push(item);
    } else {
      positiveWhenTransformedItems.push(item);
    }
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < maxDigits; i++) {
    const negativeBuckets: T[][] = new Array(10).fill(undefined).map(() => []);
    const positiveBuckets: T[][] = new Array(10).fill(undefined).map(() => []);

    negativeWhenTransformedItems.forEach((item) => {
      negativeBuckets[
        getNthDigitFromRight(partialGetValueFromIteratee(item) * -1, i + 1)
      ].push(item);
    });

    positiveWhenTransformedItems.forEach((item) =>
      positiveBuckets[
        getNthDigitFromRight(partialGetValueFromIteratee(item), i + 1)
      ].push(item)
    );

    negativeWhenTransformedItems = negativeBuckets.reduce(
      (accumulator, currentValue) => [...accumulator, ...currentValue],
      []
    );

    positiveWhenTransformedItems = positiveBuckets.reduce(
      (accumulator, currentValue) => [...accumulator, ...currentValue],
      []
    );
  }

  return [...negativeWhenTransformedItems, ...positiveWhenTransformedItems];
}
```

Mostly I'm concerned about whether or not the typings here are sane. Specifically `T extends Record<KeysCorrespondingToValueType<T, number>, number>`. Initially my intent here was to signal that any `T` should have *some* values that are numeric, but in reality that isn't a good constraint because with an `iteratee` that is a function, a numeric value can be derived from a non-numeric value (ie, converting a date string into epoch milliseconds).

Also, I am not sure if this is too much code in one example for this forum or not. If so or if there are any other issues with formatting please let me know.

Comment: What's up with that [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) `new Array(10)` ? Surely we wanted `maxDigits` in there, no?

Comment: `maxDigits` is the maximum length of a number in digits, not the radix. I suppose in other languages/situations the radix should be dynamic, but in my case I really only need to work in base `10`.